# Mouse randomly stops working using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse

Host machine: Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
Guest machine: OSGeoLive15 (Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64)
VirtualBox version:  7.0.6_rpmfusion r155176
Guest Additions installed (7.0.6)

Mouse stops working randomly using Lubuntu 22.04 as guest machine in VirtualBox. So far I don't know how to replicate the issue as sometimes happens after a few minutes and other times after hours.
I still can move the mouse across the screen, and keyboard works fine (I can open and write in a terminal, use shortcuts, etc).
Rebooting the Virtual Machine (and closing the window it was running on) solves the problem but it happens again.
I can't click VirtualBox menu, so I can't turn on and off mouse integration.

Comment: Did you install the Guest Extensions? You need to do this.

Comment: Yes I have Guest Additions installed.

Comment: I use VMware and Hyper-V with Logitech BT mice and VBOX briefly with the same mouse as on the Hyper-V machine.  No issues.  Is there a Mouse Driver you can install/  Can you try a different Mouse?

Answer (score 1):

- Host machine: Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2
- Guest machine: Windows Server 2022 Desktop Edition(Eval)
- VirtualBox version: Virtualbox version 7.0.6 r155176
- Guest Additions: version 7.0.8r156879

I'm kind of facing a the same issue with Virtualbox version 7.0.6 r155176 on Windows host. I'm running Windows Server 2022 as guest initially it was worse it was freezing randomly and often crashed during the boot and felt very slow I had a old extenstion pack so I updated the extension pack to version 7.0.8r156879 which is the latest available on https://www.virtualbox.org/

After the extension pack update performance improved slightly, it no longer crashed during boot but it still hangs randomly and the problem with mouse is still the same it just goes unresponsive to clicks and the guest doesn't respond even with keyboard and when it does its so slow and unusable

But I was a fool to think it would just solve by updating the extension pack. The screwed up thing about it is that the same setup works just fine on a old machine I have no clue what is going on.

VirtualBox Version 7.0.8 is available but I'm saw hesitant to update it but eventually went through it and I updated to latest version 7.0.8r156879I the problem with the mouse remains.

I'm considering rolling back to version 6.1.44-156814 and see it fixed.

I updated to latest version 7.0.8r156879

TLDR ->

Virtual Box v7.0.6 issue guest crashed, hangs and mouse goes unresponsive. updateing to VirtualBox Version 7.0.8  did not solve the problem consider rolling back to v6.1.44